# save_and_open_screenshot opens empty html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

This is my gem file

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
  gem 'ffaker', '~> 2.4'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
  gem 'bullet', '~> 5.5'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.12'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.8'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.3'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4', '>= 2.4.3'
end
```

When I type the `save_and_open_page` to show the page as it currently is, the snapshot opens in `gedit` and shows an empty screen. I also tried to open it in Firefox but has the same result.

How can I fix this?

Here's what I get on my screen[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you visit a page, there is nothing to show so the save_and_open_page where you're calling it from is correctly showing nothing

Comment: So this means I have placed it in a wrong position??

Comment: Yes - until you have called `visit` no page is loaded, so it needs to at least go after the visit

Comment: Ok I've moved it right before the cclick save button but doesn't open in browser (neither in the gedit)

Comment: Does the test run that far? or is it raising an error before that - there is no way that calling that doesn't raise an error or open a page if the test is getting that far.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!